# Does the supercuspidal representation becomes tempered?

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, unitary-representations, admissible-representation

I am really wondering whether supercuspidal representation may become tempered representation.

If it is not true for all classical group, is it especially true for unitary group?

If it is not true even in the unitary group, is there a representation which is both supercuspidal and tempered?

Any comments will be highly appreciated.

(Here, the unitary groups are defined over a local field whose residual characteristic is $p$)

Comment: Supercuspidal matrix coeffiicents are compactly supported, and thus tempered.